# UITableView not refreshing on reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**note: I have read similar questions, none of which answered this question specifically.** I have been trying to understand why my UITableView is not refreshing when data pieces are added to the list. I checked (through print() statements) and everytime I call `tableView.reloadData()`, it checks the length of the array to use, and does nothing from there. I even tried using this function instead:

```
func refreshUI() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    });
}
```

which I found on another answered question, but that did not fix the situation. The problem is that 
`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}` is never getting called, even though

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {}`

is returning a non-zero number when it should.

Code where new info is added to list and should be displayed:

```
   self.firebase.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock:  { (snap) in
            print("\n\n\n\n\n\nSnap Recieved from Firebase: \n\n\(snap)\n\n")

            var count = Int(self.names.count)
            var childCount = Int(snap.childrenCount)
            print(childCount)
            print(self.names)
            print("names count: \(self.names.count)")

            self.names.removeAll()

            for child in snap.children {
                let c = child as! AnyObject  
                self.names.append(c.key!)  
             }

             self.refreshUI()
           })
```

NumberOfRows method:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  print("For tableView size, returning \(self.names.count)")

    return self.names.count
}
```

Comment: How are you setting your table's data source?

Comment: Did you set the UITableView delegate and datasource property?

Comment: When do you call `refreshUI` related to adding the pieces? I guess it's a timing issue.

Comment: In your numberOfRowsInSection method are you returning the count of the array? for e.g. your method should have a statement - return arrayToLoadDataFrom.count

Comment: I initialize it with an array of strings that I get from a Database, then I update it every time there is a new one @bradkratky

Comment: @Adolfo I am using a UITableViewController and I have never had to do that before when using a UITableViewController

Comment: Is cellForRowAtIndexPath ever being called at any point, even after viewDidLoad?

Comment: @vadian Im checking right now, one sec

Comment: @YashTamakuwala yes

Comment: Please show the code where the array is populated and `refreshUI` is called.

Comment: Using UITableViewController, so thats one check out of the question. Could you show the code inside the numberOfRowsInSection method?

Comment: @ToddHopkinson it is not called at all

Comment: @vadian I added the code

Comment: Is your tableview on screen with a height > 0?  If the OS thinks that the table CAN'T display anything (due to being off screen or of 0 dimensions) it will not try to display anything.

Comment: @YashTamakuwala it is in there now

Comment: call refreshUI once after the for loop, not each time you append to your array, also pay attention to the question asked by @Putz1103 about table visibility

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint inside the numberOfRowsInSection method to check if Xcode is actually going inside the method? Because if its going inside and not doing anything then there is a possibility of a wrong cell Identifier name.

Comment: I used print() statements to do that @YashTamakuwala so I can see each time it is executed. It is executed a few times at least but the method to create the cells is never executed

Comment: @CSmith I noted that, but that did not fix the issue unfortunately.

Comment: @Putz1103 I know the tableView is on the screen and able to display because it initializes correctly

Comment: In the method `observeEventType` there is at least a closing brace missing and you should call `refreshUI` once **after** the repeat loop.

Comment: @vadian I fixed it, thank you. but it did not fix my problem unfortunately

Comment: And `snap.children` is not empty ? If it was, nothing would be added.

Comment: checking on that @vadian , give me one second and ill have ur answer

Comment: @vadian it is NOT empty, it contains and adds all the correct data

Comment: it just does not make sense to me why `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {}` is not getting called

Comment: The code looks correctly now.